# Troubleshooting "An internal error has occurred" with Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Has anyone found a way of troubleshooting *An internal error has occurred* errors with *Remote Desktop Connection*?

[image]

I've seen this error before but now I'm getting it about 95% of the time. If I keep retrying, eventually it seems to work.

I've found a few articles and tried following some of their suggestions. But none helped. And none of them attempted to address the specific error I'm getting (Error code: 0x4).

The computer I'm connecting to is a VPS on Ionos running Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting "An internal error has occurred" with Remote Desktop Connection Solved
I Posted the same problem here today but had some work around and my is solved.
this is how to do it:

Open gpeditor: `Windows Component`\ `Remote Desktop Services`\ `Remote Desktop Session-Host`\ `Security>`

Enable the policy: `Use of a specific security level for remote connection`

Select `RDP` from the drop down.

I hope it solves your problem